# Does Java have something like a JRoulette component?

Tags: java, swing, 2d-games

I am looking for a `Swing` component that combines the look of a `JList` and the go-up-and-down functionality provided by a `JSpinner` that also responds to scrolling. Does anyone know of something like this and if not, how do I craft my own `Swing`component? I need it for a game I'm trying to make...

Answer (score 0):

You can work around it like this:

```
            JList<String> list = new JList<String>(new String[]{"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"});
            list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
            list.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            list.setSelectedIndex(0);

            JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(list);
            scrollpane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 20));

            scrollpane.getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {                  
                @Override
                public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e)
                {
                    float pos = scrollpane.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue() / (float) scrollpane.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum();
                    int rpos = (int) (pos * list.getModel().getSize());

                    list.setSelectedIndex(rpos);
                }
            });

            JPanel containerPanel = new JPanel();
            containerPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            containerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 20));                                        
            containerPanel.add(scrollpane);
```

First you create a JList, then you put it inside a JScrollPane and then you add the adjustment listener to select the only element visible.

[image: Showcase]

Comment: I suppose I'll try this. Thanks a lot, kind stranger!